# Debug Azure Function App from Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure-functions

I'd like to debug an Azure Function App (that is already deployed) from Visual Studio 2022.
Earlier on Visual Studio 2019 there was an option to debug the Azure Function Apps by using the Cloud Explorer, but in the newer version that option is retired according to their documentation.
Is there a workaround for this problem?

P.S. I've seen the solutions that suggest creating a publishing profile and attaching to the process, but the Function App is already deployed so, this solution will not help.

Comment: why can't you debug them locally? That's what I do.

Comment: the issue that I have is not reproducible locally but is reproducible on the deployed version

Answer (score 2):

**You can attach the debugger by creating the publish profile in VS 2022:**

[image]

Comment: I do that and it never gets to the break point (there is a warnings)

Comment: Hello @OferGal, could you post the new question with your scenario and test cases you have done, so that it will get the attention from the whole community.