# microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions cannot be found

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I upgraded my project to .net 7 and my FunctionApp no longer works. It says that it cannot load the file or assembly Microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions because the file cannot be found.

Here is my project:

```
`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="FunctionInterfaces\**" />
    <Compile Remove="ModuleInterfaces\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="FunctionInterfaces\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="ModuleInterfaces\**" />
    <None Remove="FunctionInterfaces\**" />
    <None Remove="ModuleInterfaces\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Modules\MarketModule.cs~RF1b001614.TMP" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="ModuleInterfaces\Base\IModule.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ModuleInterfaces\IExchangeModule.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.33" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PMSX.Application\PMSX.Application.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PMSX.Domain\PMSX.Domain.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PMSX.Infrastructure\PMSX.Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>`
```

I tried removing microsoft.net.sdk.functions, but that is what specifies that the project is a functionapp. I also tried downgrading webjobs, but that had no effect.

Comment: Are you doing in vs code or Visual Studio?

Comment: @Tarun Krishna I'm doing this in Visual Studio Community 2022

Comment: Have you upgraded from .Net 6 to .Net7 ?

Comment: @Tarun Krishna Yes, that is right. I did that yesterday.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft.Extensions.X Version 7.0.0 Issue - .NET 7 FunctionApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74368240/microsoft-extensions-x-version-7-0-0-issue-net-7-functionapp)

Comment: @Hari Krishna I tried that, but ultimately, I need references to my other projects, which are all .net7. I need references to my other projects, so it cannot be isolated.

Comment: How you'll get the suitable packages if .NET 7 support not yet released for Azure Functions?

Comment: @Hari Krishna Got it. Finally got it working. But how do I debug my FunctionApp on my Visual Studio? I want to make sure it all works before I try to publish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @*[HariKrishna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16630138/hari-krishna)*  for your suggestion to solve the NuGet Package  `Microsoft.Extensions.X`  Upgrade in .NET 6 Azure Functions. It helped for me as well.

.NET 7 In-process is not yet released yet for Azure Functions V4, and your  [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74368240/16630138)  shows better solution for using the  `Microsoft.Extensions.X`  in compatible versions of Azure Functions.

> But how do I debug my FunctionApp on my Visual Studio?

You can run the function in debug mode using VS IDE for debugging locally.
[image]

Change the Release Mode to Debug > Put the breakpoints > Start running the function for debugging locally.

If the requirement is remote debugging, refer to this  [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs?tabs=in-process#remote-debugging)  and  [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71439056)  for more information on configuring the remote debugging on Visual Studio for Azure Functions Project.

Comment: Thank you, my friend. I actually also forgot to do one thing: host.Run() in the Program.cs. HAHA. I can't believe such a foolish mistake I made. But thank you everyone for the help!